# Hide border when viewing on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all I want to know if the following is possible. I am using bootstrap frame work to build a simple webpage. In the CSS I have borders on certain div elements showing as gray however when I view from the mobile a few of these divs are hidden and the border property looks very out of place. I would like to know if there is a way to target CSS elements with bootstrap so if a page is re sized to mobile the border color changes to black or doesn't show at all.

Here is a sample of my code.
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <!--Strt of row-->
    <div class="row">
    <!--leftdiv1-->
     <div class="col-sm-6" id="left1">
        <h3 class="text-center" id="main">XXXXXXX</h3>
        <p class="text-center">XXXX & XXXXX</p>
     </div>
  <!--rightdiv1-->
 <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs contacts" id="right1">
    <ul>
        <li><a id ="print" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NTGaJa5XdtVlpvQUttVWhmMXM/view" target ="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span> Download</a></li>
        <li><a id="contact" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left1 {
    border-right: dashed grey 3px;
    border-bottom: dashed grey 3px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#right1 {
    border-bottom: dashed grey 3px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You want to use media queries to achieve this and override the CSS rules, have you tried that yet?

Comment: Did you tried with visibe and hidden on different devices? Extra small devices Phones (<768px) (Class names : .visible-xs, hidden-xs) Small devices Tablets (≥768px) (Class names : .visible-sm, hidden-sm) Medium devices Desktops (≥992px) (Class names : .visible-md, hidden-md) Large devices Desktops (≥1200px) (Class names : .visible-lg, hidden-lg)

Comment: You can add your own media query rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as I see you are trying to hide the `col-xs` so the size is `<768px` [See Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)  So you would add a `@media` in your css.  This will work:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
#left1 {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#right1 {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
}
```

Comment: Superb! This did the trick. Any links you can recommend so I have a better understanding of how to use media queries?

Comment: @KurwyneGayle w3cschools link as mentioned above should give you a start.  Other than that media queries are quite simple they apply to the size of the screen you could either use `max-width` and set the `px` or `min-width` also you can use both like so `(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 600px)` God Bless.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an extra class on the element for example: `hidden-xs`. It is build in bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities